# Website development/design specification software or tool?

Tags: specifications

hello supersmart stackoverflow users!

Im wondering.. is there any software or tool (web based or otherwise) that helps and streamlines the whole technical and functional specification writing process so that we as developers/website can sit with clients, assess what they want to create/achieve and write up the spec efficiently and easily so that when its approved it can easily be passed onto the webdev people and they can create what is set out in the specification?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Specfox](http://specfox.com) is a SaaS designed just for that. You upload the screens (layouts or screen grabs), add notes and pinpoint to page elements, and generate PDFs to share with copywriters, designers and developers, or whoever you need to involve. It was the best online website specifications tool I found for a website redesign we did.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking, take a look at Axure.  It's built just for this.  It's awesome